# Hosting Font Awesome Yourself: Do we need all formats eot, svg, ttf, woff, woff2?

Tags: html, font-awesome, assets, font-awesome-5

I'm packing FA as part of my Angular 7 widget and web application using the approach [Hosting Font Awesome Yourself](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself). The thing is they explain to pack the whole `/webfonts/` folder and it contains repeated fonts in each format.

Isn't it better to stick to one format e.g. `svg` and leave the others out?

What are the cons/pros, if any, of going for one specific format only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need your web application that support in older browser too then you must host every font formats.
Unfortunately, there isn't a single format that works in all browsers, which means that we need to deliver multiple formats to provide a consistent experience.

- Serve WOFF variant to the majority of browsers.
- Serve WOFF 2.0 variant to browsers that support it.
- Serve TTF variant to old Android (below 4.4) browsers.
- Serve EOT variant to old IE (below IE9) browsers.

if you use only `SVG` font formats and leave the others out then it will support in Chrome(4.0 +), Safari(3.2 +) and Opera(9.0 +). you can [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp) the browser support for font formats.

> The WOFF is the only format that support the majority of browsers. so
>   if you can ignore the older browser then I suggest you to use WOFF
>   font formats.